# How to use the same slideshow in multiple elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using slideshow inside a modal. It works fine with one, but what would I have to do, to be able to use multiple same? I can't use unique IDs because I don't know how many will be there.

Here is my HTML for two Modals:

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
    showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    console.log(slides);
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot1");
    if (n > 3) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active1", "");
    }
    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active1";
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-item set-bg osobj" data-setbg="img/portfolio/2.jpg">
    <a class="myBtn"></a>
    <div class="myModal modal1">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal1-content">
          <span class="close1">&times;</span>
          <h2>smth</h2>
          <div class="post1-container">
            <div class="post1-thumb">

                <div class="slideshow1-container">
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis slike1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/4.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis Slike2</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/6.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis Slike3</div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</button>

                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                    </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
<!-- reference item -->
<div class="grid-item set-bg osobj" data-setbg="img/portfolio/2.jpg">
    <a class="myBtn"></a>
    <div class="myModal modal1">

        <!-- Modal content -->
        <div class="modal1-content">
          <span class="close1">&times;</span>
          <h2>smth</h2>
          <div class="post1-container">
            <div class="post1-thumb">

                <div class="slideshow1-container">
                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/3.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis slike1</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/4.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis Slike2</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides">
                        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/portfolio/6.jpg" style="width: 550px; height: 450px;">
                        <div class="text1">Opis Slike3</div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="prev1" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</button>
                    <button class="next1" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</button>

                    </div>
                    <br>

                    <div style="text-align:center">
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
                        <span class="dot1" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
                    </div>  
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

One of the problems is in slide index as it finds all my slides instead of just those 3 that are in my modal. I need to somehow confine the search of sliders just to the modal that is opened. What is the best way to do this, how to do it and why it is the best?

I played around with slide index but whit no luck, I can't seem to confine the search in javascript to just those sliders in the modal. The sliders must all use the same class "mySlides" in the modal for I don't know how many will there be and also I would like to find the solution in javascript.

Comment: well you need to code it so it does not rely on global variables.

Comment: @epascarello haha, this comment should be rewarded with some kind of medal

Comment: It is too much work for someone to sit there and rewrite all that code so it is reusable. Basically you need to wrap it into its own context and than give it selectors to know what slideshow it is pointing too. Or just find a library that already does it.

Comment: @epascarello yea, I don't know how to do that, that's why I'm posting a question for help. I tried to look only for children in each element but it still returns me all the images in all sliders combined..

Comment: So wrap it in a function, pass in the selector to reference the slide show, change the `slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");` to use that element and not the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. So for having those kind of problems, here is a solution:

```
$('.myBtn').off().on('click',function(){
        $(this).next('.myModal').each(function(i,v){
            console.log($(this).find('.mySlides'));
    });
});
```